# Resolve solidity compiler error

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, solc, compilation

I am trying to create a smart contract and I am using ganache, visual studio code and truffle for that purpose. The versions installed in my windows system are:
**Truffle v5.1.49,
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js),
Node v12.19.0,
and Web3.js v1.2.1**. However, when I include pragma solidity ^0.5.0 in my sol file I get the following error:

[image]

I have also explicitly stated the version in my truffle-config.js file, but it didn't resolve my problem.

Comment: Which editor are you using? Which plugin to highlight solidity are you using? VS Code + Solidity plugin suggest installing the correct version in the project folder.

Comment: The solidity plugin by Juan Blanco v0.0.76 in visual studio code editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed solc using npm and then specified solidity version in truffle-config.js. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Right click a solidity file, it popup a menu with the option "Solidity: Change workspace compiler version (Remote)".

[image: Change workspace compiler version popup]

After a few seconds it will show a list of available versions to select.

[image: solidity versions]

After selecting desired version it will store it in `.vscode/settings.json`.

```
{
    "solidity.compileUsingRemoteVersion": "v0.6.12+commit.27d51765"
}
```